# Call a function after the modal is rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I have a div inside reactstrap Modal, I want to call my function which grab's this div's attribute (after it has been rendered). I have tried `useEffect` on `modalShow`, I have tried useRef on that div, I have tried calling the function inside the div.

```
<div
  custom-attribute="VALUE"
  ref={modalRef}
>
    {handleModalLoad()}
</div>
```

But the problem is that my function i.e. `handleModalLoad()` gets executed before the modal is rendered therefore I am unable to grab the value from this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try make the custom div a component and use `useEffect` inside to send the value out.

Without dependency array, `useEffect` will only run when this component renders. You can get the value with `useRef` and send it out with a callback function inside `useEffect`.

You can reuse this component if you need to get any attribute value in another modal as well.

Example: (also check out the live demo: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kkmvkp?file=src/App.js))

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export function MyDiv({ handleModalLoad }) {
  const myDivRef = useRef(null);

  //  only run when this component renders
  useEffect(() => {

    //  get value from custom attribute
    const { customAttribute } = myDivRef.current.dataset;
    if (!customAttribute) return;

    //  run the function needed
    handleModalLoad(customAttribute);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div data-custom-attribute="VALUE" ref={myDivRef}>
      <h2>This is my div in modal</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState('');
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1>{`Click button to get: ${myValue}`}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => setModalOpen(true)}>OPEN MODAL</button>
        {modalOpen && <MyDiv handleModalLoad={(value) => setMyValue(value)} />}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

```js
<div
  custom-attribute="VALUE"
  ref={modalRef}
>
    {handleModalLoad()}
</div>
```

yes in this way your function will run irrespective of latest `ref` value.

do this

```js
const someRef=useRef(null)

useEffect(()=>{
     handleModalLoad()
},[someRef])

{
isModalOpen && <div
  custom-attribute="VALUE"
  ref={someRef}
>
</div>
}
```